# What bike Pump can I use for the Peugeot Savoie?

Tags: vintage, pump, peugeot

I'm trying to find a hand pump that will fit the top tube of the frame, In the model manual  attached is the Bike pump that says 'Zefal Competition HP pump' however could i use a standard 'Frame Pump' to fit into the holder shown in the second photo?

[image: Peugeot Savoie]

[image]

Comment: Please do not ask for a shoping recommendation for a particular type. I thing this could be phrased more generally about the properties of pumps that can be carried that way.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the Recommendation, what would be a better way of phrasing this?

Comment: Looks like a standard "frame pump" to me.  You just need to match the length.

Comment: Will any standard 'Frame Pump' fit in the second photo holder?

Comment: A standard frame pump is designed to fit such a bracket.  There are some (especially shorter ones) that come with brackets which you strap onto the top tube, and a few other configurations.

Comment: @JoshPeugiot: The best thing to do, is to check at your LBS. If you want to go for vintage looks only, though probably not in perfect working order, you might check at vintage parts sales. The kind of pumps came in different lengths to fit specific top tube lengths. (Old enough to have used these!)

Comment: Zefal pumps were the major French brand that came as standard with Peugeot bikes, most certainly on a business aggreement. I'm wondering whether there were any other makes in France at all. Interesting point of cycling history.